# How to play the element of the video acquired by "IntersectionObserver"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, intersection-observer

I got the video currently displayed by "IntersectionObserver".

After getting it, I want to run "play()" to play the video.
However, it seems that it cannot be executed directly from the "Element" type.
What should I do?

```
const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      // I want to play a video here.
    }
  });
}, { threshold: 0.5 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If the the `entry` is intersecting run the entries target `.play()` method:

```
entries.forEach(entry => {
  if(entry.isIntersecting) entry.target.play()
})
```

If this doesn't work, use `console.log(target)` to identify the actual target, and use DOM methods to find the actual video element.